# how to set the value of a select from a formatter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to split a time value into 2 components, the time and meridian, but have them both linked to the same ng-model value. My idea was to have validators for the values which would format and parse the values accordingly. But I can't seem to set the selected option of a select box from the validator directive.

I have an select that I have populated with the following array

```
$scope.timeMeridians   =  [ {id:'am', value:'AM'}, 
                            {id:'pm', value:'PM'}];
```

and the directive make is as follows

```
<select ng-model="editingEvent.start_date_time" 
 ng-options="option as option.value for option in timeMeridians" 
 ub-meridian-validator>
```

and the validator skeleton so far...

```
angular.module('app.MeridianValidator',[])
.directive('ubMeridianValidator',function($timeout){
    return {

        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
                    var valueType;
        // sets model based on view
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue){
                    return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z');
        });
                    // set the view format
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewValue){      
                    return scope.timeMeridians[0];
        });
    }
};
```

N.B. I have hard coded the selection logic for now until I see the value change.

So basically at the moment, not matter what value is passed to it, the viewValue formatter should return timeMeridians[0] (which is 'AM') but I doesn't change the value in the view...

I have created an input next to it and it is wired it in to duplicate the actions, all changes show up there just fine, and this method of setting the select value by referencing a position in the timeMeridians array works fine from the controller, so why not in the formatter directive?

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since realised that this was the wrong use of Angular JS formatters. The correct or better way to achieve this would be to use the ng-change directive which would call a controller function to perform the update. If your hell bent on keeping this function of the relative controller and therefor making the time input reusable, you should then encapsulate that functionality into a directive with its own controller.